# Convert binary bit string to array

Tags: dataframe, tensorflow

I have 881 bit binary string.

Example : 11000000011100000011100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000001101000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000110000000100100000001001100000000000001100100000111010000000000000000000011000000000100010000000001000100000110100100000100000000000000000100000100000000000001001000010000000000000000010001000100000000001000001100000100011001000000011000010011100110110100001000011010100011010100000100111101101100000101001011110000000010001000010001011100110000111100010001100100000100000100011100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

I want to convert it in to dataframe or .csv in tensorflow. how to do it.

Comment: what label and columns u want to assign? pls state clearly

Comment: I just want to convert this string into DataFrame, so I can use it for prediction in using my trained model

Comment: so I just need to put all of this bit into a single row? Or each row will contain single bit?

Comment: I got success by following code.
List = List(String)
H  = pd.DataFrame(np.array(List).reshape(-1,len(List)))

Comment: then submit it as your own answer and accept it. StackOverflow encourages this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer